# Angular2 Using External Javascript

Tags: angular

I am trying to use a javascript layout.js file for putting splitters on the page.

This requires the following code to be ran in the template

```
$('body').layout({
west__size: .12
, center__childOptions: {
    south__size: .5
}
});
```

I am inserting this in the bngafterviewinit as follows.

```
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    $.getScript("../Content/Scripts/jquery.layout-latest.js");
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.innerHTML = "console.log('done');";
    s.src = "../Scripts/testscript.js";
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
}
```

However this errors with .layout is not defined. It looks like the required javascript file is not being loaded before this is run.

How should I do this correctly? I am currently loading it in the index.html file.

Comment: Can you try writing `declare var layout: any;` after your imports where you use this function?

Comment: I have tried this, it doesnt seem to make a difference